How to Convert Models to SVF1 Format Before SVF2 for Faster Translation in Autodesk Forge
I'm currently working on a project where I need to convert models to both SVF1 and SVF2 formats for translation in Autodesk Forge. From what I understand, translating directly to SVF2 tends to be slower due to its higher level of detail. Therefore, I'm looking for guidance on how to first translate models to SVF1 before converting them to SVF2.
I have a function that specifies the translation job with output format SVF2:
function translateData(ossUrn) {
    var postJob = {
        input: {
            urn: ossUrn,
        },
        output: {
            formats: [
                {
                    type: "svf2",
                    views: ["2d", "3d"],
                },
            ],
            advanced: {
                conversionMethod: "v3",
            },
        },
    };
    return postJob;
}


function translateFile(res, ossUrn, bucket_file_md5, credentials, delete_manifest){
    var derivative =
        new ForgeSDK.DerivativesApi();
    if(delete_manifest == true) {
        deleteManifest(ossUrn, credentials);
    }
    derivative
        .translate(
            translateData(ossUrn),
            {},
            null,
            credentials
        ).then(function (data) {
            res.status(200).json({
                readyToShow: false,
                status: "Translation in progress, please wait...",
                urn: ossUrn,
                md5Checksum: bucket_file_md5,
            });
        }).catch(function (e) {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: e.statusMessage,
            });
        }); // translate
}


However, I'm unsure about how to modify this function or what additional steps are needed to first translate the models to SVF1. Are there specific settings or parameters I should adjust to achieve this? Additionally, any insights into the best practices for transitioning from SVF1 to SVF2 for optimal performance and detail in Autodesk Forge would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your help.

There is no guarantee that SVF1 translation is faster than SVF2. I'm not sure why you want to translate into both formats. I recommend you to use SVF2 unless there's an absolute need for SVF1.
If it's a must, one solution is to use webhooks, after getting confirmation of SVF1 translation success, you can trigger SVF2 translation.

Ok thank you, but do you have any idea how can we accelerate the translation ?

not possible to accelerate the translation, you have to wait till the translation is complete, It is better to use webhooks( https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/model_derivative_events/extraction.finished/) to get notified. For more on app resilience please read this blog: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/improving-app-resilience
